# Are there available Chrome APIs for external desktop applications?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to automate a web process and it must be done using Google Chrome because the target web site only works with a specific Chrome extension.

So far, I have been using a simple javascript code that I ran directly into the Chrome browser. But now I need to accomplish more complicated actions such as close the current window, open another URL, execute a different script... and the only way I can manage to do so is by using an external desktop application.

My first attempt was to use Visual Studio and include a "Chrome-based" (WebKit) browser control, such as CefSharp (ChromiumEmbeddedFramework), but none of them support installing extensions, so they are useless for my purpose.

My second thought was to use some of the Chrome APIs to interact between applications so that I can read the html content, open a new tab or window and execute my own javascript code at the suitable time. But as far as I understand, all provided APIs are whether to be used inside of Chrome extensions or by Chrome OS. Is this right? There is no "easy" way to have acces to Chrome from another application?

Another idea I had was to use the Remote Debugging Protocol functionality for Chrome, opening a client session in the navigator and commanding it from my application. But I am not sure about how it works and I do not think I can launch new tabs or windows from the my application, so it is not very helpful either. Furthermore, seems such a complex solution for a much easier problem.

And the last idea I came up with was to directly use an extension for Chrome to make all the work. The problem is that I do not know how extensions work and if I can execute it even when I close my target web page. For example: imagine I want to close a the current tab of the browser and open it again in 5 minutes, could it be accomplised with an extension?
I would have to learn about extensions from zero because I have no idea.

To sum up my doubts:

- Are there Chrome APIs for windows desktop applications? (or any other way to interact between Chrome and the application?).
- Do you think Remote Debugging would work for my automation purpose.
- Can an extension manage to do all the work I expect it to do?
- Do you have any other suggestion?

I hope I have explained myself clearly. I do not know much about web programming, so thank you for your help!

Best regards.

P.S: after posting this question in another forum I discovered the Chrome Apps, which are a bit different from the Chrome extensions (yes, I am not a chrome expert). I think that the Chrome apps would be suitable for my purpose. Nevertheless I would have to learn from zero how to write them and I am not very used to Js language, so I would prefer to manage with an external program written in C#, for example. 
Any idea about how to achieve this? Otherwise I will start working on how to develop Chrome apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can an extension manage to do all the work I expect it to do?

If you don't mind coding in javascript then you can do all the mentioned stuff in an extension without the debugging API. Might be even simple depending on whether your automation process includes only the mentioned stuff.

The official [extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) is a good/necessary start.
And skim through the [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) for the examples of using the API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's the thing, I would like to avoid programming in javascript because I don't have a good knowledge of it, so I would be more comfortable coding in C# the main program. Furthermore, I would have to learns about Chome apps and extensions development... Nevertheless, since the whole process is done in Chrome that would also be the most "elegant" solution.